# How to implement CSS multi-level drop down menu with different classes?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm attempting to implement a multi-level drop-down navigation menu in CSS only but there's one small part which I just can't seem to get working correctly.

What should happen is:

1) When hovering over a menu item, it should be highlighted by using a different image (this works fine).
2) When hovering over a sub-menu item, the parent menu item should be highlighted.

Point 2 works fine up until I have a class .bottom on the parent menu item (this class is used as the image is slightly different). If the parent menu item has class .bottom, the highlight simply doesn't happen.

A demo of this can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/cZFtW/2/

The demo shows that when hovering over Menu 1 > Sub Menu 3 > Sub Sub Menu X, Sub Menu 3 is highlighted. However, when hovering over Menu 2 > Sub Menu 3 > Sub Sub Menu X there is no highlight.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? On a side note, there's no real reason for not using Javascript here, I'd just prefer to have it all handled by CSS if possible (only need to support IE7+).

Comment: Get this working in a fiddle and then I guarantee people will take the time to find you a solution. This will get you started, you just need to fix links for images - http://jsfiddle.net/cZFtW/1/

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the fiddle with the image links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TL;DR; version: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/aufVB/5/) shows the answer.

---

I understand what you mean. And I am pretty sure that the styling to which you need an answer to, which works for all except for the one at the bottom, has arisen purely by accident. (Kind a nice one I must say). I am almost certain of this, because your code as well as the file names lack any form of consistancy. There is double code, there is superfluous code, and there are images missing.

Therefore I have rewritten your markup and style sheet, and came to the fiddle as mentioned above.

Now, how does it work?

The trick is to attach the background image to an element inside the list item. In this case I chose for an anchor element, since that is most the likely. The first step is to change the background image at hovering the anchor, that's basic.

The second step is to change the background again when you hover over the submenu. At that point, the anchor element isn't hovered any more, but the list item is. So you can still change the background of the anchor element.

Note: in my solution there is a small difference to what you wish: when you hover the arrow, the background if the list item is already changed instead of until the cursor is over the submenu. If you want to prevent that, then you have to add an extra element for every sub menu like you had done yourself. But I think this is pretty nice also.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great! The code wasn't actually mine, I was just given it by my designer with the assumption that I'd use Javascript to make it work but didn't feel it was necessary, which you've now proved it wasn't. Thanks.